# Where are the netlogon files physically stored?

Tags: netlogon

I have umpteen backups trying to restore my scripts I had in the netlogon share but when I go to them the folder is empty.  Does backup not back those scripts in netlogon up?  Is there somewhere I should expect to see the files at besides c:\winnt\sysvol\sysvol\mydomain\scripts?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: do you only have one DC?

Comment: I have a few but they all have the same missing files and all backups don't have them.  It just makes me think I'm looking in the wrong place.  I had a virus hit.